# Export Torque Animation

Tags: export, carto, animation

Is it possible to export a video of a CartoDB Torque animation to a file, like in ArcGIS?  If not, what are my options for displaying the animation in a presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now there is no way to export a torque animation, though export to video would be a cool new feature.

The way I'd go about it would be to make an animated gif of the torque map playing. I like [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) a lot for animated gifs. If you wanted a real video file then I'd just find a screencast software that supports the video format you want and record the animation.